# How do I print values in c# subarray?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am trying to print a user defined structure. Code:

```
        var tracksArr = new[]
        {new
            {   vessel = GetVesselInfo(aisRecord.VesselId),
                points = new[]
                {   new
                    {   stampUtc = aisRecord.Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
        }}}}
   
        foreach (var item in tracksArr)
            {Console.WriteLine("qqq: " + item.ToString());}
```

which prints:

```
qqq: { vessel = { key = 123456,0, mmsi = 7891011, imo = 0 }, points = 
<>f__AnonymousType18`6[System.String,System.Double,System.Double...
```

what is this mysterious `<>f__AnonymousType18` and how do I get the value of points?

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you get Visual Studio to format your code in the default style before posting on Stack Overflow. While it's fine for you to have personal preferences around where braces go etc, it makes it harder for everyone else to read if it's very different from the defaults which are very widely used.

Comment: Thanks John, was trying to minimize space here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) with unique set of fields (the `new { ...  }` statements in means creation of instance of anonymous type) compiler will generate a class, which name will look like `<>f__AnonymousType18`. This class has overridden `ToString` method, but arrays/collections - don't and `point`  is an array, so by default `ToString` returns type name which is `YourAnonymousTypeName[]` for arrays. You can use `string.Join` to output your collection:

```
Console.WriteLine($"qqq: {{vessel = {item.vessel}, points = {string.Join(", ", item.points.Select(p => p.ToString()))}}}");
```

Or create/use another collection type for `points` which will have overridden `ToString` method which returns string with all elements:

```
public static class ext
{ 
    public static MyList<T> ToMyList<T>(this T[] arr)
    {
        return new MyList<T>(arr);
    }
}
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public MyList(T[] arr)
    {
        AddRange(arr);
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this);
    }
}

var tracksArr = new[]
       {new
            {   vessel = 1,
                points = new[]
                {   new
                    {   stampUtc = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),               }
                }
                .ToMyList()
            }               
        }; // prints "qqq: { vessel = 1, points = { stampUtc = 2020-06-24T14:58:08Z } }"
```